# Is static pressure the pressure used in the navier-stokes equations?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, momentum

I believe in the image below, the pressure (P) being quoted is the same type of pressure that is used in the navier-stokes equations. Is this pressure the static pressure of the fluid? 
i.e. if i were to measure this pressure experimentally (i.e. experimentally verify this equation) would i use the side opening of a pitot tube (the opening that is perpendicular to the flow direction)

[image]

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Comment: @Deep You really should have posted this as answer - now this question shows up as unanswered